# How to access rows in a MultiIndex dataframe by using integer-location based indexing

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Suppose I have the following MultiIndex DataFrame, titled `df`:

```
arrays = [["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"],
          ["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"],]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["first", "second"])

df = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=index)
```

If I wanted to access all the rows associated with `baz`, for example, I would use cross-section: `df.xs(('baz'))`.

But is there a way to access the rows by referencing the integer location in the first level, similar to `iloc` for single index DataFrames? In my example, I think that would be index location 1.

I attempted it with a workaround using `.loc` as per the following:

`(df.loc[[df.index.get_level_values(0)[1]]]`

But that returns the first group of rows associated with `bar`. Which I believe its because integer-location 1 is still within `bar`. I would have to reference 2 to get to `baz`.

Can I make it so that location 0, 1, 2, and 3 references bar, baz, foo, and qux respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `levels`

```
df.xs(df.index.levels[0][1])
second
one   -1.052578
two    0.565691
dtype: float64
```

More details

```
df.index.levels[0][0]
'bar'
df.index.levels[0][1]
'baz'
```